Solidifying the clothes for game ready characters
I'm a novice, who learned various programs for 3D modeling and texturing, and right now I'm working on my portfolio. But some questions remained unanswered during my study.
One of those, is about cloth and a solidification of it. I was working on my first character and she had a dress and a long pants, which I solidified and then applied. But when I started animating, the clothes back part began to pass through its front part. I thought the problem might be in weights, but they seemed okay. I found little to none knowledge about this question in internet. Some people also had this problem and they were said to just not make solidify for the clothes, or not to apply the modifier. But how else would we make clothes actually thick? On youtube, I watched a ton of videos about creation of game ready clothes, but no one ever solidified them. Or, there were people who did solidified the clothes, but then never applied them, neither they showed their character being animated after this. Solidify without appling it works actually good, the cloth is thick and doesn't goes through itself, but we can't export a model without applying the modifier, can we? I actually tried that, but it seems like blender just applies the modifier automatically, so the program, which will get this model will have the same problems.
Just please, can somebody tell me: How the clothes are made thick for video games, so it would work properly?
For example, I played Resident Evil games and they allow to watch characters and monsters models, and they always have thick clothes, but everything is fine for them.

Did you try to add the solidify modifier, then assign weights, THEN apply the solidify modifier? This procedure should copy all weights from one vertex to its solidified twin, and so they should move in perfect syncro, without any pass through. Maybe upload your file if still in trouble.

Can you please share more info about your problem (screenshots, examples) and/or share your blend file so we can get a better idea of your issue?  Instructions for sharing blendfiles.

Sadly, I don't have the old version of my solidified mesh to show what was the problem, as I deleted all of its geometry to work with thin cloth for now. But my main question was: How the solidify modifier being treated with the cloth in the first place? Does it gets applied in the end of the work and everything should work fine? Or maybe something else is done instead?

The solution posted by josh sanfelici worked well:

Add a Solidify Modifier, then Assign Weights, then
apply the Solidify Modifier? This procedure should copy all weights
from one vertex to its solidified twin, and so they should move in
perfect syncro, without any pass through.


Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted. If no answer has been posted, feel free to [edit] your post to provide a thoroughly explained answer.
